# iOS app distribution to limited number of users

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-distribution

How to distribute iOS app to a limited number of users considering that B2B is not supported for my country? Also, is there a way to skip collecting UDIDs and not using certificates that expires in a year?

Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say B2B isn't available does that mean you cant get a Enterprise certificate issued for your business in your country ?

Comment: Custom apps (formerly called B2B) and enterprise apps are a different thing, but those are your two options. You either distribute a custom app vis AppStore Connect and Apple Business Manager or you use an Enterprise program, but this is only available for employees of your company and your company must have more than 100 users. The provisioning profile for an enterprise app must be updated once per year and the signing key once every two years.

Comment: Employees of this company are using their own personal devices, so I don't think MDM is an option for them. Anyways, Apple Business Manager is not supported in my country.
When you say that Enterprise program is only available for employees of the company, what do you mean? How the employees are identified? If I understood correctly, Enterprise program doesn't include using UDIDs in In-House certificate.